# Elasticsearch 7.11.1 not recognizing ?realtime parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to debug a major performance bottleneck after upgrading Elasticsearch to 7.11.1 - I'm experiencing slow PUT inserts/updates (which I do a lot of) and assume it relates changes to the way indexes are managed.

I found the new parameter `realtime` and thought I'd give it a shot but I get `unrecognized parameter: [realtime]` when trying it.

`GET http://localhost:9200`

```
{
    "name": "myhost",
    "cluster_name": "mycluster",
    "cluster_uuid": "uc03F4mpq1mO8CzQSzfB1g",
    "version": {
        "number": "7.11.1",
        "build_flavor": "default",
        "build_type": "rpm",
        "build_hash": "ff17057114c2199c9c1bbecc727003a907c0db7a",
        "build_date": "2021-02-15T13:44:09.394032Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "8.7.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

`GET http://localhost:9200/foo/bar/_count?q=foo:bar`

```
{
    "count": 382,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    }
}
```

`GET http://localhost:9200/foo/bar/_count?q=foo:bar&realtime=false`

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "request [/foo/bar/_count] contains unrecognized parameter: [realtime]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "request [/foo/bar/_count] contains unrecognized parameter: [realtime]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I've double checked the manual and my version. I have 7.11.1, the manual page is 7.11:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/docs-get.html#realtime

Any help appreciated.

Comment: realtime is for getting documents by id, what you have is a search query.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other parameters or settings other than `refresh_interval` that I can try to improve PUT query performance? I have `refresh_interval` set to 120s

Comment: If this is about indexing new documents then PUTs are usually very fast unless you specify `refresh=wait_for` in which case it will refresh the affected shards and wait for completion.